# How to change status of login button to logout conditionally

Tags: angularjs

Here is my login form in header html:

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-controller="loginController">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-show="$scope.loggedIn"><b>Logout</b></a>
        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-show="!$scope.loggedIn"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Index.html using ui-router:

```
<body>
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Inside the login Controller, I am setting the boolean value to true:

```
$scope.loggedIn = AuthenticationService.isLogged;
$scope.loginForm = function (email, password) {

    if (email !== undefined && password !== undefined) {
        UserService.logIn(email, password).success(function (data) {
            $localStorage.token = data.token;
            console.log("stored token is: " + $localStorage.token);
            if ($localStorage.token) {
                $state.go('LoggedIn');
            }
        }).error(function(status, data){
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

UserService:

```
   myApp.factory('UserService', function ($http, $localStorage, AuthenticationService) {
    return {
        logIn: function (email, password) {
            return $http.post('rs/loginResource/login', {email: email, password: password});
            AuthenticationService.isLogged = true;
        },
        logOut: function () {
            if (AuthenticationService.isLogged) {
                AuthenticationService.isLogged = false;
                delete $localStorage.token;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Authentication Service:

```
myApp.factory('AuthenticationService', function() {
    var auth = {
        isLogged: false
    };
    return auth;
});
```

After login, I am setting the flag to true. But the button name is not changing to Log out. I am using ui-router for changing states.

Comment: IsLogged is never set on the scope.

Answer (score 2):

You're never setting `$scope.isLogged`, just changing the service value. I'd argue that you should set `AuthenticationService` inside of your `UserService` and just check it in your controller

```
    logIn: function (email, password) {
        return $http.post('rs/loginResource/login', {email: email, password: password})
        .then(function(response){
             //Some validation here to make sure that the user was successfully logged in
             AuthenticationService.isLogged = true;
             return response;
         }).catch(function(error){/*error handling here */});
    }
....
$scope.AuthenticationService = AuthenticationService;
$scope.loginForm = function (email, password) {
   //delete this AuthenticationService.isLogged = true; 
           UserService.logIn(email, password).then(function(response){
           var data = response.data;
           $localStorage.token = data.token;
...
<a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-show="$scope.AuthenticationService.isLogged"><b>Logout</b></a>
<a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-show="!$scope.AuthenticationService.isLogged"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Comment: I get an error: `Error: UserService.logIn(...).success is not a function`

Comment: Updated the UserService and the loginController but still the button label doesn't change on login. Please check the updated question

Comment: I have put alerts inside the loginController to check `$scope.loggedIn = AuthenticationService.isLogged;` like `alert("$scope.loggedIn inside login controller: " + $scope.loggedIn);` and I can see the button status changes for a split second to logout and then back to login again. What I am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that you were using `success`.  I've edited my answer to show how to switch it to `then`.  I don't like `success` since it is only used for `$http` and creates an inconsistency in code. [here](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/) is a blog post echoing my dislike for `$http.success`. If you would stilll like to use success you would just change `then` to `success` in the `logIn` function

Comment: now error on then: `Error: UserService.logIn(...).then(...).error is not a function`

Comment: I did that. The problem is `$scope.loggedIn = AuthenticationService.isLogged;` is always returning false

Comment: Ofcourse getting the boolean from `$scope.loggedIn = AuthenticationService.isLogged;` is always false as default because setting the boolean value to true inside `UserService` doesn't have effect on scope. How do I fix this? Any idea?

Comment: Binding to the object instead of setting the value one time should allow you to see the changes to the object. I have updated my answer

Comment: hmm now the boolean returns correct value but the view isn't getting updated with `login` or `logout` buttons. It stays as "login" all the time

Comment: Did you do `ng-show="$scope.AuthenticationService.loggedIn"`?

Comment: Yes I did but still the same

Comment: Whoops it should be `ng-show="$scope.AuthenticationService.isLogged"`. updated answer

Comment: Yes I did `isLogged` only but it is still the same